# Bot framework web app service time out error

Tags: botframework

I deployed my bot in azure portal free trial and accessing the webchat using the iframe. if i left or close the chat for a while and come back to open & chat it's not working. I presume the azure bot service is down. i need to restart the bot to make the chat work.

Can any one help in this regard to avoid service down and keep alive all the time. I also enabled "Always On" option but no use.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Published C# Bot runs into internal server error after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322023/published-c-sharp-bot-runs-into-internal-server-error-after-some-time)

Comment: Check the possible duplicate for a solution if you are running bot.builder 3.14.0.7