# Microsoft Bot Framework Stopped working out of nowhere

Tags: botframework, internal-server-error, azure-language-understanding

Hello I've been using the Microsoft Bot Framework for a while now using a free student account. I have set up a Web App Bot using LUIS. This all worked perfectly fine untill yesterday. Now I've tried removing it and build it from scratch, but it's not working anymore.

My end point: https://aareon-bot.azurewebsites.net/api/messages

Everytime I try to send a message I get "failed to send message." and "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue."

When I check applicationinsight I get this message "POST to aareon-bot failed: POST to the bot's endpoint failed with HTTP status 500" and  "100% of failures came from '/api/messages' path"

Yes I have set MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword in the web config. It used to work but randomly stopped.

Does anyone know how this could happen?

Comment: Are you using bot builder SDK v3.14.0.7? If that's the case, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322023/published-c-sharp-bot-runs-into-internal-server-error-after-some-time

Comment: No I am not using the bot builder SDK. I am accessing my bot using the direct line.

Comment: yes, but how is built your bot code? In which language? If it's C#, there must be the SDK in Nuget referencs

Comment: Well I installed the bot using the portal from Microsoft. Here they have an online code editor (App Service Editor) wich is C# written, where I did some changes to the output that LUIS gives me. Besides that I have my own chat application where I use an API call to my bot framework.

Comment: Do you have a code sample of the changes you made?

Comment: I don't know how to post my code in here and make it look nice. I have edited the basicLuisDialog.cs, so it works with my intent I created in my LUIS app. Still I don't think the problem lies here, because I haven't changed anything to it and it just randomly stopped working. Also I rebuild it from scratch without changing any code and still I get the same error. First I thought it had to do something with my license but that wasn't the case. After that I thought I maybe reached the limit of my requests but I'm at like 900 requests, so that shouldn't be the case either.

Comment: Are you hosting this in Azure?  If so, have you tried restarting the web app the bot is on?

Comment: Yes it is hosted on Microsoft Azure using the portal.azure.com. Also tried restarting and recreating it from scratch. I'm really out of options atm.

Comment: I have created a new account using a creditcard this time and it works perfectly fine now. I think it had something to do with my account not having the rights anymore to use the resources. Thanks everyone for your input and trying to help me fix my problem.